# Two methods for solving bivariate optimization problems — how do they compare?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Consider the unconstrained non-convex optimization problem:

$$\min\limits_{x,y} f(x,y)$$

Suppose that for fixed $x$, the function $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is convex. In this case, I believe there are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Just solve the optimization for both variables $x, y$
2. Obtain the implicit equation $y^* = h(x)$, which is the solution of $$\min\limits_{y} f(x,y)$$ for fixed $x$ — relatively easy and unique from the convex property, and then solve $$\min\limits_{x} f(x,h(x))$$

I'm curious how these two methods compare — which is generally preferable, and in what cases do individual methods have merit? Also, are there any useful references related to this?

Comment: 1. How do you "just solve", it is non-convex. Without saying anything else about f there aren't any strong results for this problem. 2. "relatively easy" if there is a closed-form solution/LP/etc., yes, but in general this is not easy. Also, the statement "and unique from the convex property" is not true either. Unless you assume it is strongly convex, strictly convex + other assumption to ensure it exists, there can be multiple or no solutions. Without additional assumptions on f I don't think you can really say much about what is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. To further narrow down the problem, let's think of $f$ as a non-linear least square form, and for fixed $x$, $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is still non-linear least square, but strongly convex.

Comment: Also, we can employ standard Gauss-Newton (or other variants) to solve both $\min\limits_{x,y} f(x,y)$ and $\min\limits_{y} f(x,y)$ for fixed $x$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean "non-linear least square form", this isn't a standard term. I don't really know how you can state that Gauss-Newton works since this is a non-convex problem, generally, this is not true. Clearly, there are other assumptions at play for you to be able to say this. To make it more obvious what the problem is, assume that $f(x,y) = y^2 + g(x)$, for some non-convex function $g$. This satisfies all the properties you have, we can solve for $y$ since it isn't coupled with $x$, i.e., $y=0$ is the optimal value for any $x$.

Comment: Regaudless of which method you choose (option 1 or 2 you mentioned above), the preferences will be the same. The issue is that the non-convex part has all the complexities. Without describing how $x$ and $y$ interact or some other property on $f$, the question is way too open ended. We could represent almost any function we could imagine with these properties.